How to process information from a modern Sharepoint page, article type, with api MSFT
I know that the content of a SharePoint page is stored in CanvasContent1 and that I can retrieve it using the item ID:
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(1)?$expand=ContentType
or using the page name:
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=Title,FileLeafRef,CanvasContent1&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'Employee.aspx'
From here I get, among others, the SchemaXml, CanvasContent1 and LayoutWebpartsContent attributes
I also tried adding /FieldValuesAsHtml, /FieldValuesAsHtml, /FieldValuesAsText or /ContentType to the URL, but I basically get the same information.
I have also tried this GRAPH API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{mysiteid}/pages/{mypageid}?expand=canvasLayout
I know that pages have sections and columns.
This is all I know, but now I don't have an idea what to do with all this information. I have managed to use all the other graph APIs and SharePoint for my purpose, which is to show the list of news from a site, but now I can't show the detail of the news due to the complexity in handling all this information.

You can do it with PnP PowerShell (and maybe with PnP Code SDK):
Get-PnPPage 
Get-PnPPageComponent

PnP Cmdlets:

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPPage.html
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPPageComponent.html

